# findByIdAndUpdate returns 200 response but does not update

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

Sending a put request by findAndUpdateById which returns a 200 response in postman - but the data is not updated.

The put request is

```
app.put("/api/report/update/:id", (req, res) => {
  Report.findByIdAndUpdate(
    req.params.id,
    req.body.data,
    { new: true },
    (err, report) => {
      if (err) return res.status(404).send({ message: err.message });
      return res.send({ message: "report updated!", report });
    }
  );
});
```

The shape of the data sent is

```
    report: {
            month: "",
            updateMajor: "",
            updateMinor: "",
            comments: {
              comment1: "",
              comment2: "",
              comment3: ""
            },
          }
```

The data is returned exactly as sent.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Check the content in `req.body` with a `console.log(req.body)` it's most likely not containing what you are expecting it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use some `update` operator like `$set`, `$unset`, `$push` etc. in your update query. since you are not using any of those you are getting this behaviour.

If you just want to set the value that you are sending, Try using it with `$set`.

Try this:

```
  Report.findByIdAndUpdate(
    req.params.id,
    {$set : req.body.data } ,
    { new: true },
    (err, report) => {
      if (err) return res.status(404).send({ message: err.message });
      return res.send({ message: "report updated!", report });
    }
  );
```

Note : $set overrides previous value.

If you need something else, please read detailed information in [MongoDB update Operators Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/)

Comment: Actually using mongoose ( as the question actually is ) the `$set` is implied and automatically added to the actual statement sent to MongoDB. You can see this with `mongoose.set('debug', true)`. So no, that's not the issue.

Comment: $set worked I also had to send along each field and value instead of body.data